IBM i5 model 9405
I found a model i5 on eBay, expected delivery in about ten days. So I don't know yet if it is in working condition at all, but I am doing some homework beforehand. The IBM website was helpful, but still, maybe someone knows this:

Are these systems still maintained? Not bij IBM, but maybe some other companies do? The system is old, but not ancient, so I can imagine they still run in the wild.
As far as I know the system comes without an admin-terminal. Do I need a specific terminal type? And are those still sold somewhere, or do I look for vintage here too?
As I understand this system runs OS/400 and Linux. Can I expect it to allow another linux device to ssh in?
The AS/400 had a physical key needed to IPL/boot, and if I read correctly so does the i5. But what if that is not included? Is it possible to replace the lock? Have IBM make a new key?

Thanks for any advice you have.

how is this retrocomputing ? Other than the fact that current linux doesn't support power5 any more

@camelccc If you don't think it's on-topic, you can vote to close; though I think these systems are borderline, so maybe taking it to [meta] would be wise as well.

@camelccc Time marches on. The Power5 is 20 years old. Remember also that questions like this come here because they don't necessarily have good places for answers elsewhere.

This question needs more focus. It asks 4 basically independent questions. It would be better split.

I forgot, StackExchange, where people like to tell you your questions are wrong, because why be helpful?

@ABMK people are very helpful but you need to be focused and on topic. Not hard!
